# Is there a version of JSFiddle for Meteor?

Tags: meteor

Is there anything like JSFiddle for Meteor? It would be great to be able to share code problems I'm having so others can see both the client and server side of my code as well as see it run.

Thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Looks like there is something out there now! Really great to see something. Should be helpful.

http://meteorpad.com

Comment: Looks like this site is down now

Comment: Yea, the site owner took it down, it was costing him to much time and money I believe.

Comment: Are you aware of any alternatives?

Comment: No, as far as I know there aren't any. If Meteor ever gets an ```npm install meteor``` command then I believe it would work on something like JSFiddle